# few portion gets lost in expect tcl

Tags: tcl, telnet, expect

I have a expect script which telnets to a router and gives a command and logs the output. the following snippet should be the ideal output.

```
==========================================================================
slot          type            number       number       rev.     addresses
----   ------------------   ----------   ----------   --------   ---------
0/0    GE-4 IOA             4306297694   4500006802     A04          4    
0/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
1/0    GE-4 IOA             4306255468   4500006802     A04          4    
1/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
2/0    GE-8 IOA             4306211660   4500009102     A05          8    
2/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
3/0           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
3/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
4/0           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
4/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
5/0    OC3/STM1-8 ATM IOA   4305503226   4500006903     A02               
5/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
7/0    SRP IOA              4306297292   4501006502     A00          2    
11/0   Service IOA          4306516819   4501007103     A00               
11/1          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
12/0          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
12/1          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
13/0      GE-4 IOA             4306255468   4500006802     A04          4    
13/1          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
14/1          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
15/0          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
15/1          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
==========================================================================
```

but what I get is this... the 13/0 line is corrupt and 13/1 goes totally missing and this is fairly consistent - only those lines gets corrupted. I have set match_max to 60000. and I even added "sleep 10" after sending the command.

```
==========================================================================
slot          type            number       number       rev.     addresses
----   ------------------   ----------   ----------   --------   ---------
0/0    GE-4 IOA             4306297694   4500006802     A04          4    
0/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
1/0    GE-4 IOA             4306255468   4500006802     A04          4    
1/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
2/0    GE-8 IOA             4306211660   4500009102     A05          8    
2/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
3/0           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
3/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
4/0           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
4/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
5/0    OC3/STM1-8 ATM IOA   4305503226   4500006903     A02               
5/1           ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
7/0    SRP IOA              4306297292   4501006502     A00          2    
11/0   Service IOA          4306516819   4501007103     A00               
11/1          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
12/0          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
12/1          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
13/0   G    ---   
14/1          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
15/0          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
15/1          ---              ---          ---         ---         ---   
==========================================================================
```

cant figure out why this happens.

here is the code

```
if {[info exists router_name]} {
    spawn telnet $router_name
    sleep 3
} else {
    return "Spawner<< No router_name\n"
}

##newly added
expect -re ".*>|.*#" {
        exp_send "term len 0\n" 

    puts "issuing show hard"
    expect -re ".*>|.*#" {  
        exp_send "show hard\n"
    }

    #sleep 10
    #puts "issuing newlines"
    expect -re ".*>|.*#" { exp_send "exit\n\n\n\n" }
} -re ".*login.*|.*name.*" {
    if {[info exists router_username]} {
        exp_send "$router_username\n"
    }   
    exp_continue
} -re ".*word*" {
    if {[info exists router_pass]} {
        exp_send "$router_pass\n"
    }   
    exp_continue    
} 

expect -re ".*" {}

close
```

the line exp_send "show hardware\n"; is the command given - I need the output of that command.

Comment: Interesting; the length of the output to the point of corruption is ~1500 bytes. The only thing I can think of that correlates with that sort of thing is some sort of Ethernet packet frame size, or possibly the MTU. ***WHY WOULD THAT MATTER??*** TCP is supposed to insulate us from this sort of thing…

Comment: You might be best working around this by setting [`terminal length`](http://www.cisco.com/web/techdoc/dc/reference/cli/nxos/commands/fund/terminal_length.html) to, say, 15, and making your expect script know how to handle the paging. Which would be an ugly workaround, but at least possible…

Comment: And before anyone asks, my knowledge of the fine details of expect is shaky and my knowledge of Cisco router firmware wholly non-existent. I can google stuff, but you can do do that too. (Or someone else can tell you how to do it through a proper answer.)

Comment: @DonalFellows: thanks I will try the one you said in the second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @DonalFellows suggested - doing the workaround did the job.

adding a segment to detect "--More--" and to send "\n\n" the output is received without out break.

here is the code after changing

```
if {[info exists router_name]} {
    spawn telnet $router_name
    sleep 3
} else {
    return "Spawner<< No router_name\n"
}

expect -re ".*>|.*#" {
        exp_send "term len 0\n" 

    puts "issuing show hard"
    expect -re ".*>|.*#" {  
        exp_send "show hard\n"
    }

    #sleep 10

    expect -re ".*>|.*#" {
        exp_send "exit\n\n\n\n"
    } -re ".*--More--.*" {
        exp_send "\n\n"
    }

} -re ".*login.*|.*name.*" {
    if {[info exists router_username]} {
        exp_send "$router_username\n"
    }   
    exp_continue
} -re ".*word*" {
    if {[info exists router_pass]} {
        exp_send "$router_pass\n"
    }   
    exp_continue    
} 

expect -re ".*" {}

close
```